# uCommerce Category Facet

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, umbraco-ucommerce

A requirement of a site I am working on is that you have facets on a site wide search result, I am therefore not using the FacetsForCategory method to work with Faceted search. I am using the SearchLibrary.FacetedQuery() to return an IFacetedQueryable and calling ToFacets on that.

This is working fine for all the fields we have defined, however iwould like a Category facet returned too as the results of the search return products in many categories. This would be the most useful facet for the search.

I can't find out how to get uCommerce to return category though, any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you can't get it to add a category facet via the basic APIs. The data must exist so maybe it requires you to start implementing the pipeline.